# tm symbol wont show up as it should in html, sm symbol works tho

Tags: html, css, wordpress, symbols

i cant make the TM symbol to show up as it should, the SM symbol is working fine. The test page you can see is located at http://codita.ro/test/
I have deleted both reset.css and normalize.css and its not because of the resets..
Here's the page if you can track this down so i dont have to wrap the symbol in a span across the site to make it look smaller.

example of code:

```
 the SkinLaze&#0153; aesthetic
```

Comment: Add your code in your question. Linking to a site with no code is bad practice. See [FAQ] for more.

Comment: i have added a sample of the code im using in the post, sorry thought i mentioned im using the html symbols... on the test site you can see they appear big on the same line as the text and not small as they should   i have used both the decimal and hex versions of the tm symbol

Comment: I'd guess your font doesn't support the trademark glyph. To test, change the font to something more normal (like maybe `font-family: serif;`) and see if it starts working.

Comment: yes it now works but i didnt think at this because the other symbols are working fine except the tm :) no solution but to continue to wrap it in a span and vertical-align: super;   ... ?

Comment: One thing you could do is drop back into a font that supports the glyph you need. (I have vague memories of some browsers doing this for you automatically, but I could be wrong.) <span class="hack">™</span>, and apply a working font-family to the `hack` class.

Comment: thanks alot, this is the best solution i can see. i would mark as answer if you too :) cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symbol “™” is there, just pointlessly small (I copypasted it from the page into this message). This is a flaw in the design of the font being used.

If you cannot change the font, consider using a different font for “™” and probably for “©” too (it looks broken). The simple way to do this is to wrap the occurrences in `span` elements with `class` and use CSS to set the font on them. A more modern, but somewhat less cross-browser way, is to use `@font-face` with `unicode-range`.

The reference `&#0153;` is incorrect by the specs; `&trade;` and `&#8482;` are correct. But nowadays all browsers accept `&#0153;` too.

Answer (score 1):

On my tool [AmpWhat HTML entity reference](http://amp-what.com/#q=trade), use the "f" button at the bottom to try out different fonts. Some have custom glyphs, and some fallback to other fonts. Although not its primary purpose, you can explore what characters are supported in different fonts.

Alternatively, use sup<sup>tm</sup> element, as in `<sup>tm</sup>`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use HTML entities for that character. Use `&trade;` in your HTML. More about HTML Entities you can find out [under this link](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp)

Comment: The page is correctly declared as UTF-8, as far as I can see. Is there a specific reason why you think using ™ (like I just did here) wouldn't work? (Not a criticism of the answer, I'm just curious.)

Comment: it appears you were right, read above comment. the darn font supports all symbols but tm !

Comment: I see now that there's a strange behavior there. If everything else fails try using <sup>tm</sup>

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the font you're using, Tinos Regular, doesn't support the [trademark symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trademark_symbol).

I'm no expert on workarounds for this sort of thing, but the first that springs to mind is to drop back to a font that includes the glyph:

```
/* CSS */
.fallback-font {
   font-family: serif;
}

<!-- HTML -->
This is trademarked<span class="fallback-font">™</span>.
```

EDIT: While our solutions are basically the same, I'd defer to Jukka on this one, who clearly knows what he's talking about more than I do :D

Comment: i did as you suggested but it was you who helped the most :) cheers

Answer (score 0):

Might be that if you use `™` directly in your HTML instead of the `&trade;` but you didn't set your charset to UTF8. In such cases it can end up rendering completely malformed.

Make sure you set the charset to UTF8.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  ...
</head>
  <body>
    ...
  </body>
</html>
```

Read more on the importance of the meta charset here [in this nice blog post on dev.to](https://dev.to/maggiecodes_/why-is-lt-meta-charset-utf-8-gt-important-59hl) and [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta#charset).